# Strange domain fowarding

Tags: .htaccess

My client has a shared hostingprovider, were he can setup multiple domains on 1 hostingaccount. we have the following problem.

example: if you type.. www.domain.com... u go to.. www.domain.com (nothing wrong) however if u type domain.com (without www.) u go to www.domain.com/domain.com

so it fowards (once) you to a map (on the server) which has the same name as the domain.  after the one time foward.. u can click on home and go to www.domain.com and everything is fine.

so it seems that this one time fowarding happens only if u type it in the url bar without www.

the hostingprovider is claiming its a coding problem, its not PHP, because it happens even if the php-file is totally empty of any code, they say it might be a htaccess problem, although i have never had this problem before on any other hostingcompany, but this company doesnt give any support on this problem so i need to find the solution myself

current htacces code is

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^cms/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^test/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^plesk-stat/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|css|flv|js|swf|php|ico|webm|mp4)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+\.php)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

besides this code, it also contains mod_deflate.c  and mod_expires.c code, but this didnt seem relative to the problem

i cannot find where or how this htaccess file is creating this problem, and i was hoping you guys could help me

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: great, that seem to do the trick, thank you, if possible and if u can id like to learn what i did wrong in the code

Comment: @user2461508 because .? means each character ( so if you type `http://example.com/bla`, it redirects to `http://www.example.com/blahttp://www.example.com/blahttp://www.example.com/blahttp://www.example.com/bla` (4 times = for each char of /bla). You can use your code with ^.*?$ (matches anything or nothing)